# Can I get list of my company's installed apps on device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to know that is it possible in iOS that one could get list of installed applications uploaded by same company?? If yes, then what would be the code???

I know that it's restricted to get list of installed apps in iOS. But I want to know that which of my applications are installed on user's device? So, does Apple allows to get list of own installed apps??

Answer (score 3):

If you did some planning in advance and gave each app it's own URL scheme then you could check if each scheme in turn was openable by the app and count the number that were. But if your apps don't have defined schemes then no, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Well for the ***Second part*** of your question. Yes you can get the list of apps installed in your device using

```
-(void) allInstalledApp
{    
    NSDictionary *cacheDict;    
    NSDictionary *user;    
    static NSString *const cacheFileName = @"com.apple.mobile.installation.plist";    
    NSString *relativeCachePath = [[@"Library" stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Caches"] stringByAppendingPathComponent: cacheFileName];    
    NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"../.."] stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeCachePath];    
    cacheDict    = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];    
    user = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"User"];    
    NSDictionary *systemApp=[cacheDict objectForKey:@"System"];
}
```

The systemApp Dictionary contains the list of all system related app and user Dictionary contains other app information.

According to your ***First part*** of the question , you cannot directly get the list of apps for a particular company . **But** You could show a constant URL of the Apple store site to the user in a `UIWebView` or outside the app in Safari . This URL would have the list of all the apps. Also if you have the list of the URL's your app's loaded on the Apple store . then you could show them individually in the browser too.

Comment: Please ask this in the Apple forums.... they would provide you with a better solution...

Comment: @IronManGill: It is working in simulator, but in real device. It is not working.

Comment: @IronManGill Gill Saab eve kiven installed applications return ho gayian ethe? NSHomeDirectory() tan Current executing application da path hai.. istob back ja k baki application tan dekh hi ni sakde kise ho sandbox ch.. Chahe vakul nu puchh lao :-p

Comment: @KsK puch leya vakul nu ... kenda kuch samaj ni aa raha k what u want to say :P ....

Comment: Do you want to get info about if PDF converter is installed or not from other app?

Comment: Yes read twice.. He wants to know about  other app from one app .. right?

Answer (score 0):

no, nothing You ask is possible, of technical and local reasons.
You can see some details only on YOUR devices you configured with IPCU or similar tools, (MDMs..) but not in code.